# the program is not accepting today's date. it gives me error (the program should only accept today's date and date in the future )

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, oracleforms

```
PROCEDURE ALERT_DATE_TAKEN IS X VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN 
    IF :VEHICLE_RENTAL_BLOCK.DATE_TAKEN < SYSDATE THEN 
        X:=SHOW_ALERT('DATE_TAKEN_ALERT'); 
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to include the error code.

Answer (score 2):

`SYSDATE` has a time component.  If you want today's date to not generate the alarm, then use `TRUNC()` to remove the time:

```
IF :VEHICLE_RENTAL_BLOCK.DATE_TAKEN < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: @MTB don’t say _thanks it’s working_, instead accept then answer (tick check-mark next to the answer) and also consider up-voting this answer.